# Jquery1.7.1 causing screen to shrink on mobile and tablet

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, tablet

The static website I am working on works fine on all browsers, however when I look at it on mobile or tablet - on load everything will quickly shrink for a half a second. It looks like it loads it a pixel or two bigger, then when everything is loaded it will shrink. Just to test I took out the Jquery and the problem goes away. Does anyone know the solution, or what it is in the Jquery that causes this problem? Also the site cant have viewport or responsive - the user wants it to look how it does on a desktop site.
Thanks very much!

- M

Comment: jquery, natively doesn't have any think like that.

Comment: it would help to see your css, html and what mobile browsers you are having problems with.

Comment: It's almost certainly not jQuery *per se* but what jQuery is specifically employed to do.